# Should I worry about creating a module for each controller, service, directive etc

Tags: angularjs

I've noticed some people define a new module for each controller, service, directive etc.

```
angular.module('controllers.Dashboard',[]).controller(...);
angular.module('controllers.Details',[]).controller(...);
angular.module('controllers.List',[]).controller(...);
```

However, isn't that a performance issue? I mean: for each controller you create, you also create a new module.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

Any performance hit would be incredibly minimal. What you do gain in terms of performance though, is testing speed. Testing can be localized to small modules that don't need to load in the entire application to perform what they need to.

On the code organization side, I personally like the idea of breaking up modules depending on feature not architectural slice. So instead of having a module for controllers, a module for services, etc, create a new module for every new feature/piece of the application. This way you can group together conceptually related controllers, views, services, filters, and so on.

Comment: I agree with organising by feature, and I'm using ng-boilerplate as a framework for that reason - it provides clear structure for that grouping.

Comment: +1 for mentioning ng-boilerplate PaulL, forgot to include that. It is a very good resource for starting new projects. Hopefully there's a Yeoman generator for it soon though.

Comment: Yes - josh is currently updating to a new version that will be npm installable and upgradeable - refer some commentary here: https://github.com/ngbp/ng-boilerplate/pull/168.  Very much looking forward to that.

Comment: I see. The thing is that in my app I will need all my controllers and directives etc as dependencies from the start as I won't be lazy-loading any. Not sure if it's worth having so many modules and module names and having to insert all 30 controller modules to the dependency list of the app for example versus having one controller module and just listing that.

Answer (score 1):

The overhead will be minimal in practice.  It is really more of a code organization type issue.  On my project we have a FooService, FooController,FooDirectives, BarService...

Comment: You mean FooController, FooDirective etc as one per module?

Comment: @Francisc one per module yes.  So you could say FooControllers, FooDirectives (with an S)